# How to get resources from JSF validator?

Tags: jsf, resources

I have a small java web app and want to have access to some resources during validation.
I know how to do it in servlet since I can use ServletContext, but I don't know how to access it from my validator code.
Resources can be stored in WEB_INF folder or inside packages, but when I tried `Class.class.getResourcesAsStream()` it always returned `null`.
I feel like I'm doing something wrong, but cannot get what is.

Comment: Hi, see [ask]  and act accordingly (something about an mcve

Answer (score 0):

Well alternatively you can get a file then put an InputStream on it

```
String path = "resources/images/image.png"
ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getContext();
    String  realPath = ctx.getRealPath("/");
File file = new File(realPath + path);
```

if the file is in a package then the path would look like

```
String path= "WEB-INF/classes/package/file"
```